# Inefficient ctor/dtor order when reallocating std::vector

Tags: c++, stdvector, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I played around with the [copy elision example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) and noticed some odd behavior when reallocating a std::vector:

[for gcc 10.1 / clang 10.0.0]:
When using move-constructors, every move-ctor is immediately followed by a dtor. However, when using copy-constructors, first all ctors are called, and only then dtors. The latter is possibly inefficient when the class is large.

Is there some requirement that reallocation with copy-constructors behave in this manner?

Note: For icc 19.0.1 the behavior is consistant in both cases, but sub-optimal.

Here is the [code](https://godbolt.org/z/h5sPxM) I used to test this (try removing `noexcept` from move-ctor):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

struct Noisy {
    inline static int count = 0;
    Noisy() : data(1000) {
        std::cout << "constructed: " << ++count << "\n";
    }
    Noisy(const Noisy& other) : data(other.data) {
        std::cout << "copy-constructed: " << ++count << "\n";
    }
    Noisy(Noisy&& other) noexcept : data(std::move(other.data)) {
        std::cout << "move-constructed: " << ++count << "\n";
    }
    ~Noisy() {
        std::cout << "destructed: " << --count << "\n";
    }

    std::vector<double> data;
};

std::vector<Noisy> f() {
    std::vector<Noisy> v(2);
    assert(v.size() == v.capacity());
    std::cout << "---------------\n";
    v.emplace_back();
    std::cout << "===============\n";
    return v;
}

int main() {
    f();                     
}
```

Comment: Read about [strong exception safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety)

Comment: @StaceyGirl You're saying that if the reallocation fails, the vector should remain unaffected? If so, is there a way to ensure that it doesn't fail (as is the case with move-ctors)? Adding `noexcept` to the copy constructor doesn't help...

Comment: Vector only cares about `noexcept` on move constructor, but not copy-constructor because it is not very useful - any allocating constructor might throw, non-allocating ones are usually fast. If one day C++ standard library starts assuming that small allocations do not fail (marking allocating function `noexcept` becomes a common practice), then vector might be optimized for this. Otherwise it is just not that useful.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Once the additional size for the vector `v`, and for one additional `Noisy` class was allocated, there's no need in additional memory (if the copy constructor is `noexcept`). Is there another reason for a reallocation to fail? Specifically when using copy-ctors but not move-ctors?

Comment: My point is that vector assumes that copy-constructor is always allowed to fail, but move-constructor _might_ be allowed to fail. Cases when copy-constructor is `noexcept` but still allocates memory are non-existent, so there was no optimization made for that case.

Comment: If the constructor cannot throw, then the order of construction/destruction doesn't matter in 99.999% of cases. And in the 0.001%, just use the move ctor. No, wait, use the move ctor in 100% of cases. Why would you ever want to use a copy ctor for moving?